# moving TFS project collection that wasn't detached

Tags: tfs

I'm attempting to attach a collection from one TFS server to another. This collection was not detached before restoring on to the new server.  Both are TFS 2010.

The problem is that when attempting to attach the collection, it return an error saying the collection was not detached properly. The old TFS server has been removed completely.

Is there a way to force attach such collections or any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [tfsconfig recover](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407077.aspxBlockquoteblah)  command to attempt to repair a collection that was not detached correctly.

> The Recover command is not reversible and should not be used except after the standard attempts to restore the databases for a deployment have failed.

> This command should be used only when a server failure or database synchronization failure resulted in a state where a collection or project could not be completely restored and reattached from backups.